# Why is a transposed pandas dataframe smaller than its original?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which I checked the size of with sys.

```
sys.getsizeof(df)
# output: 136
```

If I transpose it I get

```
sys.getsizeof(df.T)
# output: 341
```

If I transpose twice I get

```
sys.getsizeof(df.T.T)
#output: 136
```

How is pandas managing the memory?

UPDATE:

I used `df.memory_usage` instead to yield the following (which confused me even more as copying yielded smaller in memory size). Is this related to the datatypes of the objects? Or maybe the column and index strings?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Total Unique Authors": author_count,
                              "Earliest Year": [earliest_year],
                              "Latest Year": [latest_year],
                              "Total Reviews": [total_reviews]})
print(df.memory_usage().sum())
print(df.copy().memory_usage().sum())
print(df.T.memory_usage().sum())
print(df.T.copy().memory_usage().sum())
```

OUTPUT

```
112
112
224
64
```

Comment: Don't use `sys.getsizeof`, `df.info()` is a better indicator of usage. `df.memory_usage()` is better still.

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks. I've made some changes and still I get interesting results that I can't explain...thoughts as to their cause?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from `sys` documentation:
Return the size of an object in bytes. The object can be any type of object. All built-in objects will return correct results, but this does not have to hold true for third-party extensions as it is implementation specific.

Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.

however, I cannot reproduce your finding:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3))
print(sys.getsizeof(df))
print(sys.getsizeof(df.T))
```

leads to

```
344
344
```

As commented by coldspeed, `df.info()` or 'df.memory_usage()' is more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've made some updates to my code. See if you can reproduce the data with strings in the column names and indices. I think that's where the memory disparity might be coming from, but I don't really understand it.